# Css background-image issue

Tags: html, css, background-image

I am trying to set this image: http://www.flaticon.com/free-icon/linkedin-logo_34405#term=linkedin&page=1&position=1 as my background image, but it doesn't work...

> Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped.

Code(HTML):

```
<div class="linkedin"></div>
```

Code(CSS):

```
.linkedin {
    display: inline;
    background-image: url(../images/Linkedin(Idle).png);
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}
```

Comment: Where do you get that error? BTW inline elements don't have width or height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `display: inline;` with `display: inline-block;`, also add background properties:

```
.linkedin {
    display: inline-block;
    background-image: url('../images/Linkedin(Idle).png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 0;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked i am going to accept as soon as stackoverflow let's me.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
.linkedin {
    display: inline;
    background-image: url('../images/Linkedin(Idle).png');
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}
```

The parenthesis in the middle are interfering with the parser, and it's assuming the image ends right after `Idle)`